# Div height problem when there is padding?

Tags: html, css

I have a div...

here's the css

```
div#bounty_def
{
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    height:0px;
    font-size:12px;
    top:90px;
    background-color:#352b22;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
```

The problem is that when I use padding along with height:0px, the div still appears on screen.  Since, I'm using jquery to animate this div, I can't use visibility:hidden or anything like that.  So how can I make this div "disappear" with the padding so that I can animate the height of the div later?

Thanks!

Edit:
I don't want to animate both padding and height at the same time cause it doesn't look as I want it to.
I tried using two functions (one for padding, one for height) to animate, but there's a pause in between animations.  If there wasn't it'd be perfect.  Anyone know how to get rid of the pause?

Answer (score 0):

Why not start with zero padding an animate that as well?

Comment: looks weird to me, so I was hoping to avoid doing this.

Answer (score 0):

It shows up because of the combination of the `background-color` and the `padding`. If you animate it, can you just set the padding to a value of 0 before the animation starts, and on the ending of the animation, set it back to the values it had before?

Comment: true, that makes sense, however the top part of text also show up so i'm gonna need a different solution